# Move folder in Android Safe Folder?

Tags: android

Anyone knows how to move a folder or sub-folder (not files) to Safe Folder (feature in the Google Files app) in Android?

It doesn't seem, this is supported - only files, and I wonder why?

If this is not possible, anyone can recommend an alternative way in Android to protect/hide folders?

Thank you in advance!